# Getting the Git push branch to Jenkins multi-configuration project user-defined axis

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I have a project in which there are two branches. The `develop` branch needs to be build everytime code is pushed to the branch and `master` should only run when manually performed. I came across the multi configuration project in which I can use parameters to specify different build commands for both the branches. I could write `develop/pom.xml` for my `develop` branch and `master/pom.xml` for my `master` branch with respect to the folders. But I want to use a parameter in place of the branch name like `$branch/pom.xml` where the `$branch` value should be obtained from the branch which was pushed to. Is this possible? If not is there any work around to this?

Comment: Can't you use a server-side hook? If I remember correctly such a hook accepts reference name as one of the arguments.

Comment: server side hook doesn't take any arguments right?

Comment: It doesn't. The script is passed couple of arguments including name of the reference which was modified. So you can make use of it within the script.

Comment: can you help me with an example script. I can't find any understandable resources on writing post-receive hooks :(

Comment: Every git repository has a update.sample file in the .git/hooks directory. Also check this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create two Jenkins projects:

- *develop-build-trigger* (Freestyle)
- *build-given-branch* (Maven)

and configure [Git Plugin > Push notification from repository](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository):

> To minimize the delay between a push and a build, it is recommended to set up the post-receive hook in the repository to poke Jenkins when a new push occurs. To do this, add the following line in your `hooks/post-receive` file, where `<URL of the Git repository>` is the fully qualified URL you use when cloning this repository.
>
> ```
> curl http://yourserver/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>[&branches=branch1[,branch2]*][&sha1=<commit ID>]
> ```
>
> This will scan all the jobs that:
>
> - Have *Build Triggers > Poll SCM* enabled.  No polling *Schedule* is required.
> - Are configured to build the repository at the specified URL
> - Are configured to build the optionally specified branches or commit ID

See also [Pro Git, 8.3 Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

### `<Your repo>/.git/hooks/post-receive`

```
curl http://<Your Jenkins>/git/notifyCommit?url=<Your repo>&branches=develop
```

### Freestyle project *develop-build-trigger*

- **Source Code Management**

  - ◉ Git

    - Repositories

      - Repository URL: `... your repo ...`
    - Branches to build

      - Branch Specifier: `develop`
- **Build Triggers**

  - ☑ Poll SCM
- **Post-build Actions**

  - Trigger parameterized build on other projects

    - Build triggers

      - Projects to build: `build-given-branch`
      - **Predefined parameters**

        - Parameters: `branch=develop`

This project will be triggered on `post-receive` since it specifies `develop` as branch to build, which conforms to the branch given in the `post-receive` hook URL.

### Maven project *build-given-branch*

- ☑ This build is parameterized

  - **Choice Parameter**

    - Name: `branch`
    - Choices:

      ```
      master
      develop
      ```
- **Source Code Management**

  - ◉ Git

    - Repositories

      - Repository URL: `... your repo ...`
    - Branches to build

      - Branch Specifier: `$branch`
- **Build**

  - Root POM: `$branch/pom.xml`

*Build with Parameters* and confirm the default value `master` for a manual `master` build. (As an added benefit you can build `develop` manually, too.)

A disadvantage is that you check out your `develop` branch twice, once in each project.

With that said I also want to mention that it is unusual to have different POMs for the same project. If there are different views to a project, if different things should be done depending on these views Maven supports [Build Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> They modify the POM at build time, and are meant to be used in complementary sets to give equivalent-but-different parameters for a set of target environments (providing, for example, the path of the appserver root in the development, testing, and production environments).

This means in your case that ***Build*** → *Root POM* stays empty and  → *Goals and options*: `-P $branch` (with `master` being the `<activeByDefault>` profile that doesn't change anything on the configuration).

Comment: can you help with an example script to be put into the post-receive file which would trigger the jenkins URL only for the develop branch and not for master? Because master needs to be built manually :(

Comment: @mayooran Is it clearer now that I updated my answer?